# mktime is not working for years greater than 2038

Tags: php

I am using php version 5.3.8
And mktime is not working for me

here is the code

```
$dated= mktime(0,0,0,11,5,2038);
var_dump($dated);
```

Output is as bool(false) 
Please suggest me its fix

Comment: Suggest update to 64-bit PHP or use DateTime objects as a way of hadling date values outside of the 32-bit limit

Comment: exactly as the max valid year limit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php):

> Before PHP 5.1.0, negative timestamps were not supported under any
>   known version of Windows and some other systems as well. Therefore the
>   range of valid years was limited to 1970 through 2038.

One possible solution is to use [ADOdb Date Time Library](http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/adodb_date_library). This library overcomes the limitations by replacing the native function's signed integers (normally 32-bits) with PHP floating point numbers (normally 64-bits).

Comment: Can I ask what's negative about this?

Answer (score 4):

mktime returns timestamp, which is an integer (and in PHP it's a signed integer actually). Hence the max possible timestamp for 32 bit system is `19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC` (after that an integer overflow occurs). For greater timestamps you need a 64 bit integers.

Answer (score 2):

Three important things about converting time using C/C++ library.

gmtime() or localtime() from standard library convert from time_t to struct tm, but the resolution for time_t is seconds from epoch. So fractional seconds will not count.

mktime() converts backwards from struct tm to time_t, but it will return -1 if the input date is out of range. (Refer the year 2038 problem on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

If you are not using 64bit timestamp, even you run programs on 64bit machines, you still have year 2038 problem. There are 64bit version functions like gmtime64(),localtime64(), mktime64() that may resolve the year out of range issue. (Refer page: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frtref%2Fmktime64.htm)

Answers that using boost library cannot solve the year 2038 problem. Notes that from its page: "Internally boost::gregorian::date is stored as a 32 bit integer type."